# to read out vs to read aloud vs to read out loud

Tags: difference, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between the following sentences in terms of meaning?

- > Children ​love to have ​stories read aloud to them.
- > Children ​love to have ​stories read out to them.
- > Children ​love to have ​stories read out loud to them.

---

- > The attorney read the will aloud in front of the whole family after gathering them in her office.
- > The attorney read the will read out in front of the whole family after gathering them in her office.
- > The attorney read the will read out loud in front of the whole family after gathering them in her office.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I don't think this question should have been closed. Unlike synonyms in a dictionary, the differences between _read aloud_ and _read out loud_ won't be readily found in easily-obtained sources. Nonetheless, since the first close vote was cast by the O.P., I'll let the matter stand for now.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no difference in *meaning*; all three of those are grammatical and understandable.

Honestly, though, the *out loud* (or *aloud*) part is implied and can be omitted:

> Children love to have stories read to them.

Sometimes, though, writers will include "out loud" (or "aloud") for emphasis.

Books on this subject sometimes include the word *aloud*, and sometimes leave it out, as this screen shot of a Google Books search shows:

[image]

Comment: However you say it, just make sure you read to your kids.

Comment: How about the other example?

Comment: @Mrt - It's not ungrammatical, but it's not very common, either.